# How to split the string (by matching a set of regular expression) into tokens and print each token in JAVA?

Tags: java, regex, string

**Problem Statement**

Given a string s , matching the regular expression [A-Za-z !,?._'@]+, split the string into tokens. We define a token to be one or more consecutive English alphabetic letters. Then, print the number of tokens, followed by each token on a new line.

**Input Format**

A single string, s.
s is composed of English alphabetic letters, blank spaces, and any of the following characters: !,?._'@

**Output Format**

On the first line, print an integer,n, denoting the number of tokens in string s (they do not need to be unique). Next, print each of the n tokens on a new line in the same order as they appear in input string s .

> **Sample Input**
>
> He is a very very good boy, isn't he?
>
> **Sample Output**
>
> 10
>
> He
>
> is
>
> a
>
> very
>
> very
>
> good
>
> boy
>
> isn
>
> t
>
> he

**My Code:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*; 
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = scan.nextLine();
        scan.close();
       String[] splitString = (s.replaceAll("^[\\W+\\s+]", "").split("[\\s!,?._'@]+"));
            System.out.println(splitString.length);
            for (String string : splitString) {
                System.out.println(string);
              }
}
}
```

This code works fine for the Sample Input but do not pass this test case.

> **Test case:**
>
> **Input:**
>
> ```
>        YES      leading spaces        are valid,    problemsetters are         evillllll
> ```
>
> **Expected Output:**
>
> 8
>
> YES
>
> leading
>
> spaces
>
> are
>
> valid
>
> problemsetters
>
> are
>
> evillllll

**What changes in the code will pass this test case ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speaking about trimming non-word chars in the beginning of the string, your regex is not correct.

The [`^[\\W+\\s+]`](https://regex101.com/r/Hsy8Lr/3) matches 1 character at the beginning of a string, either a non-word (`\W`), a `+` or a whitespace. Using `replaceAll` makes no sense since only 1 char at the start of the string will get matched. Also, `\W` actually matches whitespace characters, too, so there is no need including `\s` into the same character class with `\W`.

You may replace that `.replaceAll("^[\\W+\\s+]", "")` with `.replaceFirst("^\\W+", "")`. This will remove 1 or more non-word chars at the beginning of the string (see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Hsy8Lr/2)).

See [this online Java demo](https://ideone.com/HilXIf) yielding your expected output.

NOTE: to split a sentence into word char chunks, you may actually use

```
String[] tokens = s.replaceFirst("^\\W+", "").split("\\W+");
```

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/HMgfdJ):

```
String s = "       YES      leading spaces        are valid,    problemsetters are         evillllll";
String[] splitString = s.replaceFirst("^\\W+", "").split("\\W+");
```

Then,

```
System.out.println(splitString.length); // => 8
for (String string : splitString) {
    System.out.println(string);
}
// => [ YES, leading, spaces, are, valid, problemsetters, are, evillllll]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the online java demo link. It passed the intended test case and all other test cases except for 1. 

> Test case:

> INPUT: (No INPUT STRING)

> EXPECTED OUTPUT:

> 0

Comment: Just to make sure: did it also fail before? I think yes. So, the string = `""`, right? I suggest checking with `if (s.isEmpty())` and if not use splitting.

Comment: No it did not fail before, and yes string =" ", Even this change did not pass the test case. 

`if (s.isEmpty()) { System.out.println("0"); System.out.println(s); } else{ String[] splitString = (s.replaceAll("^\\W+", "").split("[\\s!,?._'@]+")); System.out.println(splitString.length); for (String string : splitString) { System.out.println(string); } `

Comment: [Here is *your* code](https://ideone.com/5owUKc) with `s = " "`, and it shows 1. However, you should check a *trimmed* input with `isEmpty()`. See [this demo](https://ideone.com/y4CArG)

Comment: Voila.. All test cases passed with this change in the code,

`if (s.trim().isEmpty()) {
   System.out.println(0);
        }`
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one it's working

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = scan.nextLine();
        scan.close();
        
         s = s.trim();
        if (s.length() == 0) {
            System.out.println(0);
        } else {
            String[] strings = s.split("['!?,._@ ]+");
            System.out.println(strings.length);
            for (String str : strings)
                System.out.println(str);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can trim the string before splitting it. In the given test case, it will count blankspace at the starting of the string as well. Try this:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = scan.nextLine().trim();
        if(s.isEmpty()) 
            System.out.println("0");
        else {
        String[] S = s.split("[\\s!,?._'@]+");
        System.out.println(S.length);
        for(int i=0;i<S.length;i++) {
            System.out.println(S[i]);
        }
        }
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(s.trim().isEmpty()){
   System.out.println("0");
   System.out.println(s);
} else {
   String[] splitString = (s.replaceAll("^\\W+", "").split("[\\s!,?._'@]+"));
   System.out.println(splitString.length);
   for(String str: splitString) {
        System.out.println(str);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = scan.nextLine();
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s,("[_\\@!?.', ]"));
        System.out.println(st.countTokens());
        while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
            System.out.println(st.nextToken());
        }
        scan.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = scan.nextLine();
         String[] arr = s.split("\\s+|\\,+|\\'+|[\\-\\+\\$\\?\\.@&].*");  
    // Write your code here.
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){

            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
          scan.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be better to add some explanation to the code. At least to your regular expression

Answer (score 0):

The following should help

```java
  public static void regexTest() {
    String s="isn't he a good boy?";
    // Replace any non alphabetic characters with a space.
    // [^a-zA-Z]
    // [          - Start a custom character class
    //  ^         - Anything that is not
    //   a-zA-Z   - a lowercase character or upper case character.
    //              for example a-z means everything starting from 'a' up to 
    //              and including 'z'
    //         ]  - End the custom character class.
    // Given the input string, the single quote and question mark will be replaced
    // by a space character.
    s=s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", " ");
    // Split the string (that only contains letters and spaces into individual words.
    String[] array_s=s.split(" ");
    for(int i=0;i<array_s.length;i++) {
        System.out.println(array_s[i]);
    }
```

Comment: I've found it is a good idea with Regular expressions to comment them construct by construct as they are often somewhat cryptic to people. In your case, a simple comment on the replaceAll would help alot.

Answer (score 0):

This will pass all test cases

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = scan.nextLine();
    if(s.trim().isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println(0);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(s.trim().split("[!,?. @_']+").length);
        for(String a : s.trim().split("[!,?. @_']+")){
            System.out.println(a);
            }
        }
    scan.close();
    }
}
```